# Running a Gulp task async, but only when needed

Tags: asynchronous, gulp

Gulp's async tasks seem pretty straight forward, and I'm using them for a lot of "first clean the directory, then build the LESS"-style async tasks.

I'm stuck on one, however, and I'm sure it's my frame of reference. I'm hoping someone can talk me through the logic of it.

- **build-changelog** grabs my current git log and turns it into markdown. It uses git tags as headers
- **increment** increments my version number and applies it as a git tag
- **deploy** packages everything up and copies it to a versioned folder on the server

**Deploy** is dependent on increment * build-changelog (we never want to deploy to the same versioned folder). **build-changelog** has no dependencies (it can be run to make a changeling at any time) EXCEPT when paired with deploy. In that case, it also needs to wait for increment to finish.

If anyone could help me out with how I'm mis-thinking about this, I'd be grateful!

nz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd be very concerned that you have a task that can "make a [changeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changeling) at any time".

Moving on....This is the kind of thing that's a pain in the neck with gulp's current clunky task dependency system.

For now I suggest this:

```js
function changelog (cb) {
  // ...
  cb();
}

gulp.task('build-changelog', changelog);
gulp.task('deploy:build-changelog', ['increment'], changelog);

gulp.task('increment', function (cb) {
  // ...
  cb();
});

gulp.task('deploy', ['deploy:build-changelog'], function (cb) {
  // ...
  cb();
});
```

Comment: That gave me a good laugh  (and I'm not editing it!) I'm sad to hear that it's Gulp's issue (not mine), but I like this solution. I get too caught up in everything needing to be a task and forget you can just write good old fashioned functions.

Comment: I had a good laugh too when I first saw the original :) I believe they're streamlining this kind of stuff a lot in gulp 4. Not long after posting this answer I saw someone discuss a technique in a blog post that might be applicable here -- have a "main" task that sets up other tasks. In other words `gulp.task('main', function (cb) { gulp.task('sub', some_func); })` I haven't tried it, but that might be another way to get the result you want.